# How to restore properly my internet connection after VPN has been disconnected?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, powershell, batch

I'm looking for a method to restore properly my internet connection after VPN has been disconnected.

So i created this batch file in order to check my internet connection and try to repare and restore it with this command :

```
CMD /C %SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe Skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI
```

**The Problem seems that can't solve the issue internet connection after disconnecting from the VPN ???**

**So my question is there any command or even powershell command that can restore my internet connection ?**

The Complete Batch code : ***Check_Internet_Connection.bat***

```
 @echo off
 Title Checking Internet Connection & Mode 70,4 & color 0B
 ::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 REM First We Check The Status Of The Internet Connection
 Call :Check_Connection 
 ::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 :Main
 Title Your Extrenal IP Address
 Mode 50,4 & Color 0A
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (
    'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:" ^| findstr /v "208.67.222.222" '
  ) Do ( 
    If "%%A" NEQ "127.0.0.1" (
        set "ExtIP=%%A"
    ) else (
        Color 0C & echo(
        echo              No internet connection !
    )
  )
  echo(
  If defined ExtIP (
    echo       You are connected to the internet !
    echo       Your External IP is : %ExtIP%
  )
  Pause>nul & Exit
 ::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 :Check_Connection
 Title Checking Internet Connection ...
 SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Mode 50,3 & Color 0B
 echo(
 echo(  Please Wait... Checking Internet Connection ...
 Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
 Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000>nul
 cls
 echo(
 if [!errorlevel!] EQU [1] (
    Color 0C & set "internet=Not Connected To Internet"
    echo(  Connection Status : !Internet!
    CMD /C %SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe ^
    Skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI
    Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul & Goto Check_Connection
 ) else (
    Color 0A & set "internet=Connected To Internet"
    echo(    Connection Status : !Internet!
    Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul & Goto Main
 )
 EndLocal
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What VPN client software are you using?

Comment: The VPN that i use is : Seed4Me

Comment: So you are using the client software they provide, correct? You can also not use the software, check the guides on the Seed4Me homepage. I’m having trouble downloading their client, so I cannot check it out at the moment.

Comment: @DanielB 
Yep, I think this is the most possible reason for that !
From their [FAQ](https://seed4.me/pages/faq)

The Kill-Switch is a feature that is written into the software of top VPN providers that, when enabled, will make sure your IP Address isn't accidentally exposed in case of a dropped connection with the VPN server.

When enabled, the kill-switch will instantly kill your internet connection in the event the VPN connection fails

Answer (score 0):

The network interface - Wi-Fi or wired - has two layers: physical and logical. Physical is whatever you can touch, everything else is logical.

The IP addressing configured for the NIC creates a logical interface that allows the system to communicate with the external world. Adding a VPN creates a separate logical interface, the tunnel between your system and the VPN provider. When the VPN disconnects, the OS has to switch from one logical interface to another, and Windows (or the driver) doesn't always handle such sudden changes gracefully.

Two things you could test when it's in failing state:

1. Give commands `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` to force new settings
2. Give command `netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dhcp`. You can find the correct interface name with command `netsh interface ip show config`.

If either of these options work, you can just add it to your script.

To simplify troubleshooting I'd ping an IP address instead, for example Google's DNS `8.8.8.8`. If you run the script and the ping works but browsing fails, you already know you have an IP and the gateway works, so something's failing in DNS. If ping to DNS name fails there are multiple possible points of failure.

Comment: A VPN client wouldn’t do that. It will have its own (virtual) network adapter that it manages.

Comment: ... which in practice means adding a new, independent logical interface on the physical adapter and changing the OS traffic forwarding so that it uses the VPN adapter instead of the non-VPN:d one. When you disconnect from the VPN the OS has to switch from one logical adapter to another, which is the kind of change Windows doesn't always handle gracefully. But you're right, I'll fix my answer accordingly :-) But first, coffee :-)

Answer (score 0):

See why what your VPN is doing that it does not restore your network settings. This does not normally happen to me or customers I deal with.

Try running TCP/IP and DNS Reset:

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
>
> (1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
>
> (2) ipconfig /flushdns
>
> (3) restart the computer and test.

Comment: When i restart my computer without typing any commands it works normaly. I think this can be happen from security issue, there is something blocking it! But i don't know what exactly , perhaps My Bitdefender ?

Comment: Bitdefender normally should not interfere with Network connection. The network settings are getting upset (why I suggest Reset) and check the settings in your VPN setup.

Comment: @Hackoo When you restart your OS will need to request the IP address again, which is exactly the same process I'm referring to on my answer. You can test those commands on the command line, and just add to the script whatever works - if any.